# Angular 2: Inline styles & templates (a la Reactjs) vs externals?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template

I have been investigating the inline styles & templates vs externals in the new Angular 2 components.

I was wondering what is the recommended route. I know it doesn't matter as far as functionality is concerned.

Having styles and templates together in the component reminds me of how reactjs tackles things. It does have its advantages.

Code Completion etc? Is this better for inline vs external? I am unsure which route to take or which is recommended.

Comment: I think answer depends upon one's view and how your requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about encapsulation and uniqueness of the component.  Sometime you run into situation where certain elements require some special styles.  With the traditional css, you would create a unique class, sometimes use !important to make sure it applies....

with ng components, your component can share global style and at the same time have it's own unique styles.  Furthermore, component's styles can be contain within itself and/or share globally, given you more flexibility to do what you want.

https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-controlling-how-styles-are-shared-with-view-encapsulation?series=angular-2-fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

From https://angular.io/styleguide

> **Extract Template and Styles to Their Own Files**
>
> Style 05-04
>
> **Do** extract templates and styles into a separate file, when more than 3
>   lines.
>
> **Do** name the template file [component-name].component.html, where
>   [component-name] is our component name.
>
> **Do** name the style file [component-name].component.css, where
>   [component-name] is our component name.
>
> **Why?** Syntax hints for inline templates in (.js and .ts) code files are
>   not supported by some editors.
>
> **Why?** A component file's logic is easier to read when not mixed with
>   inline template and styles.